# Does $Floor(1-\frac{1}{n})$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis

Does $x_n=Floor(1-\frac{1}{n})$ converge? I want to say no but I'm uncertain.

Suppose it converges. Then $\lim x_n=1 - \lim Floor(1/n))=1$
But there exists no N such that $|x_n-1|<\frac{1}{2} \ \forall n\ge N$, contradiction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does converge, note that for every natural number $n$, we have $0 < 1-\frac{1}{n} < 1$. This means that $x_n = \lfloor{1-(1/n)}\rfloor = 0$ for every natural number.

Hence, $x_n \to 0$. That is, if you fix $\epsilon > 0$ and take $N = 1$, if $n > N$, then $|x_n| = |0| = 0 < \epsilon$

You made a mistake in assuming $\lfloor{1-(1/n)}\rfloor = 1 - \lfloor{1/n}\rfloor$

Comment: Does this depend on the definition of floor? If we floor towards 0, Floor(1-1/n)=1-Floor(1/n) so diverges?. If we take the greatest integer less then, as you correctly say, converges?

Comment: No, there's only 1 standard definition for the floor function. If you have a real number $x$, the floor function of $x$, denoted $\lfloor{x}\rfloor$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$. For example, $\lfloor{2.9}\rfloor = 2$, $\lfloor{20.9999999}\rfloor = 20$, and $\lfloor{10.1}\rfloor = 10$ and so on